# responsive nav not toggling when i click the icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the margin and width functions to work so i can proceed to the styling. I await your kind rsponses, thank you very much.

```
 <nav class="navbar">
        <span class="open-slide">
            <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
        </span>
       
    </nav>
    <div id="slide-menu" class="side-nav">
        <a href="#" class="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">FAQ</a>
        <a href="#">Lgout</a>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <h2>A responsive slide bar</h2>
    </div>


    <script>
        function openSlideMenu() {
            document.getElementById("slide-menu").style.width = "250px";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px;"
        }
        function closeSlideMenu() {
            document.getElementById("slide-menu").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById("main").marginLeft = "0";
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change a tag to button tag.

Here You can grab article when to use which tag.
https://medium.com/design-code-repository/a-vs-button-b859547cae4d

Also You can improve Your code by adding eventListner rather than 'onclick'.

```js
function openSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('slide-menu').style.width = '250px';
  document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '250px;';
}

function closeSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('slide-menu').style.width = '0';
  document.getElementById('main').marginLeft = '0';
}

const openSlideMenuBtn = document.getElementById('open-slide-menu-btn');
const closeSlideMenuBtn = document.getElementById('close-slide-menu-btn');

openSlideMenuBtn.addEventListener('click', openSlideMenu);
closeSlideMenuBtn.addEventListener('click', closeSlideMenu);
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <span class="open-slide">
    <button id="open-slide-menu-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
</nav>
<div id="slide-menu" class="side-nav">
  <button class="btn-close" id="close-slide-menu-btn">&times;</button>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">FAQ</a>
  <a href="#">Lgout</a>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <h2>A responsive slide bar</h2>
</div>
```